# Getting device token for AWS SNS push notification using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) for angular capacitor project

Tags: angular, firebase, push-notification, amazon-sns, capacitor

I want to use AWS SNS for push notification using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) from a Angular Capacitor and Node+Express tech stack project. Can someone help in what all things are required and guide step by step. I looked on net but did not find a solid solution.